# difference in accessing input stream in POST and PUT

Tags: php, httprequest

I made a simple file:

```
$t1 = file_get_contents('php://input');

$t2 = file_get_contents('php://input');

var_dump(strlen($t1), strlen($t2));
```

when I send data over **POST**, both t1 and t2 have same data in them, but when I send them by **PUT**, only t1 (*first one to access* ) has data and second one is empty

why is that??

BTW my php version is 5.3.13

Comment: because its only read once. its in the manual. read the [note](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

Comment: read only is not *read one time only* stream!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see here: [Supported Protocols and Wrappers - php:// — Accessing various I/O streams](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

[image: Manual]

The manual says...

- You can repeatedly read `php://stdin` in any cases with **5.6.***
- Maybe you can repeatedly read `php://stdin` with **5.5.*** or older version if the request method is `POST`.
- You cannot repeatedly read `php://stdin` with **5.5.*** or older version if the request method is `PUT`, `PATCH` or `PROPFIND`.

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: 5.3.13 but still I don't get your answer